# Flex TitleWindow simulate drop and prevent dragging for a few seconds?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, move, drag

I wish while I am dragging and moving around TitleWindow instance and a specific event occure to simulate drop of the window, and not further moving been possible for a few seconds.

*It is very unusual question but it will be more than handy each point to a solution*

P.S: The whole idea is as follow: When I am dragging a TitleWindo instance with the mouse, and if the TitleWindow hit the border of it's parent container then to drop the TitleWindow, and not further moving is possible (simulating release mouse button). If I wish to move it again, then I should click the TitleWindow title again and grag it.

Comment: What kind of specific event are we talking about here?

Comment: something, just changing some property to true, or something like this.

Comment: Please be more clear as to what you're trying to achieve exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Yordan:

Let's see if I understand you correctly.  The demo below will "stop" a window from being drug offstage.  When you try to drag it off the top or left border, it will "simulate the release mouse button" as you requested.  The right and bottom border won't cause this to occur.

**AutoDropTitleWindow.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="setup()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        private function setup() : void {
            var titleWin:MyTitleWindow = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, MyTitleWindow, false) as MyTitleWindow;
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(titleWin);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

**MyTitleWindow.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300"
           creationComplete="setup()"
           >

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.events.TitleWindowBoundsEvent;

        private function setup(): void {
            addEventListener(TitleWindowBoundsEvent.WINDOW_MOVING, dragWatcher);
        }

        protected function dragWatcher(event:TitleWindowBoundsEvent):void
        {
            if (event.afterBounds.left < 0) {
                event.afterBounds.left = 0;
                dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
            } else if (event.afterBounds.right > systemManager.stage.stageWidth) {
                event.afterBounds.left = systemManager.stage.stageWidth - event.afterBounds.width;
            }
            if (event.afterBounds.top < 0) {
                event.afterBounds.top = 0;
                dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
            } else if (event.afterBounds.bottom > systemManager.stage.stageHeight) {
                event.afterBounds.top = systemManager.stage.stageHeight - event.afterBounds.height;
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Label x="10" y="10" text="X:"/>
<s:Label x="10" y="30" text="Y:"/>

<s:Label x="40" y="10" text="{this.x}"/>
<s:Label x="40" y="30" text="{this.y}"/>

</s:TitleWindow>
```

Comment: Killer Example! Just tested it. Thank You very much ! :)